# Continuously calculating averages over past intervals w/ Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be a really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am don't feel really confident on working with timestamps so I could not sort that problem by my own.

I made the following example, which represents a simple case of what I have been working on. There, you can see that I have made up a dataframe consisting of a speed signal (which is an input) over a period of one hour.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = pd.Timestamp('2019-11-15T16:00')
end = pd.Timestamp('2019-11-15T17:00')
t = np.linspace(start.value, end.value, 60*60+1)
data = pd.DataFrame([])
data['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(t)

noise = np.random.normal(0,1,3601)
data['Speed'] = 10*abs(np.random.randn(3601))+noise
```

I am going to implement a controller, which will limit that speed signal, but that not on the scope of the question. So what I am looking for is a way in which I can loop through the column `for i,val in enumerate(data['Speed'].values):` and calculate the mean speed over the last 10 seconds for each loop. So the idea is for each new iteration, calculate the mean over the past 10 values.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one! Suggestions of what to look up for are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.mean.html#pandas.core.window.Rolling.mean

```
data['Speed_10s_mean'] = data['Speed'].rolling(10).mean()
```

result

```
    Timestamp           Speed       Speed_10s_mean
0   2019-11-15 16:00:00 6.467616    NaN
1   2019-11-15 16:00:01 1.233462    NaN
2   2019-11-15 16:00:02 9.136592    NaN
3   2019-11-15 16:00:03 18.617069   NaN
4   2019-11-15 16:00:04 7.628102    NaN
5   2019-11-15 16:00:05 11.840941   NaN
6   2019-11-15 16:00:06 7.788474    NaN
7   2019-11-15 16:00:07 13.069130   NaN
8   2019-11-15 16:00:08 5.549147    NaN
9   2019-11-15 16:00:09 0.596765    8.192730
10  2019-11-15 16:00:10 13.273170   8.873285
11  2019-11-15 16:00:11 19.339124   10.683851
12  2019-11-15 16:00:12 18.659298   11.636122
13  2019-11-15 16:00:13 4.094160    10.183831
14  2019-11-15 16:00:14 13.240686   10.745089
15  2019-11-15 16:00:15 17.535431   11.314539
16  2019-11-15 16:00:16 28.936041   13.429295
17  2019-11-15 16:00:17 6.081373    12.730520
18  2019-11-15 16:00:18 16.009562   13.776561
19  2019-11-15 16:00:19 1.101115    13.826996
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I guess that in my case, that won't work. My idea is to calculate when loop the average of the last 10 previous values.